# What makes this JSON invalid?

Tags: json

We have an API that returns the following JSON output, but every JSON validator I paste the output into says that the JSON is invalid. Can anyone tell me why?

```
{"s924vpmm":{" {"day":30, "dayofyear":334, "daysinmonth":30, "freqstr":"M", "is_leap_year":false, "month":11, "ordinal":574, "qyear":2017, "start_time":1509494400000, "week":48, "weekofyear":48}":50.8188}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes `"` within the keys of your JSON:

```
{"s924vpmm":{"{\"day\":30, \"dayofyear\":334, \"daysinmonth\":30, \"freqstr\": \"M\", \"is_leap_year\":false, \"month\":11, \"ordinal\":574, \"qyear\":2017, \"start_time\":1509494400000, \"week\":48, \"weekofyear\":48}":50.8188}}
```

It's now valid, although I will say it's very odd that one of your JSON keys is an entire string-ified JSON object.